# Date minus 30 days error

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working on this function that compares today's date with an expiration date. The input: expireStamp, is a timestamp in milliseconds.

```
compDate = function(expireStamp) {
    // expireStamp is a timestamp, convert it
    var expireDate = new Date(expireStamp);
    var notifyDate = new Date().setDate(expireDate.getDate() - 30);
    var today = new Date(); // today

    console.log("Today: " + today);
    console.log("Notify: " + new Date(notifyDate));
    console.log("Expire: " + expireDate);

    if(today.getTime() <= notifyDate) {
        // date is still good
        return "good";
    } else {
        // date may be expired
        if(today.getTime() > notifyDate && today.getTime() <= expireDate.getTime()) {
            // date soon to expire
            return "soon";
        } else if(today.getTime() > expireDate.getTime()){
            // date has expired
            return "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 dates to check today's date against, the expire date and the notify date which is 30 days before the expire date. The problem I'm having is with the notify date. If I set the expire date too far in the future, the notify date acts weird. Here's some example tests:

```
> var exp = new Date(1409362782000)
undefined
> exp
Fri Aug 29 2014 21:39:42 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
> var notify = new Date().setDate(exp.getDate() - 30);
undefined
> notify
1396183229815
> var test = new Date(notify);
undefined
> test
Sun Mar 30 2014 08:40:29 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

So, I set the expire date to August 29th (today is 4/4/2014), using a timestamp in milliseconds. That's quite a bit in the future. As you can see, exp is correct.

Notify date is supposed to be 30 days BEFORE exp but notify is March 30th which I am sure is way more than 30 days before August 29th. With dates closer to today it is fine.

**I need the notify date to be 30 days before the expire date**

Comment: I guess, you are wrong about what `getDate/setDate` functions are.

Comment: I found `setDate(exp.getDate() - 30)` from somewhere on the internet when I searched subtract n days from a date in javascript. Is there another way to subtract days from a date?

Comment: `notify = new Date(exp.getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))`

Comment: HEY! That worked! Write that as an answer so I can accept it. So the `(30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` is 30 days, 24 hours, 60 minutes, 60 seconds, 1000 milliseconds right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> exp = new Date(1409362782000)
Sat Aug 30 2014 05:39:42 GMT+0400 (MSK)
> notify = new Date(exp.getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
Thu Jul 31 2014 05:39:42 GMT+0400 (MSK)
```